# Vbscript that scans for a certain name of a drive, instead of drive letters and copies files to that usb drive name

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I am trying to figure out how to make a vbscript that will scan for a USB device with a specific name and then once located copy a file to it.

Example instead of scanning for drive letter `J`, scan for a specific name corresponding to the specific USB device I want to copy to.

Lets say my USB device I want to locate is named `TEAM`, I want the script to scan for the name `TEAM` instead of a drive letter and copy files to it. I want it this way because drive letters can change one time my USB device named `TEAM` might be letter `J` next it might be `E`.

This way it doesn't have to worry about if the drive letter changes and will always be able to get to my device unless of course I change the USB device's name.

I am new to programming and I've made a script that will scan for a letter but I'd like to change it so it uses the USB name instead of drive letter.

Thanks help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ask WMI for the required information

```
Option Explicit

Function getDriveLetterFromVolumeName( volumeName )
Dim volumes, volume

    ' Unless we found a matching volume, an empty string will be the returned value
    getDriveLetterFromVolumeName=""

    ' Ask WMI for the list of volumes with the requested label
    Set volumes = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") _ 
                  .ExecQuery("SELECT DriveLetter FROM Win32_Volume WHERE Label='" & volumeName & "'")

    ' If exist an matching volume, get its drive letter
    If volumes.Count > 0 Then 
        For Each volume In volumes 
            getDriveLetterFromVolumeName = volume.DriveLetter
            Exit For
        Next 
    End If

End Function

WScript.Echo getDriveLetterFromVolumeName( "TEAM" )
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

So, once we are able to determine if it is available and what the drive letter is, the only remaining task is copy a source file to the target drive

```
Dim fileToCopy
    fileToCopy = "c:\source\folder\myfile.txt"

Dim usbDrive
    usbDrive = getDriveLetterFromVolumeName( "TEAM" )

    If Not (usbDrive="") Then 
        With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If .FileExists(fileToCopy) Then
                .CopyFile fileToCopy, usbDrive & "\targetFolder\myFile.txt"
            End If
        End With 
    End If
```

Comment: MC ND The code you provided executes but a empty message box pops up and that is it. Was i supose to add something to the code??

Comment: @Travy641, the `getDriveLetterFromVolumeName` return an empty string in the case a volume with the indicated label has not been found. This is the empty message box, the `wscript.echo` with an empty string because a matching volume has not been found.

Comment: Ok i figured it out i renamed it and unplugged it and reconnected the device now it recognized it when i run the script, how could i make use of that script and add a function or something that will execute a copy file function and then check the script for the device letter to auto copy to that device. Sorry for the question in comment box. Thanks

Comment: @Travy641, sorry, rereading my answers i have seen i updated the answer and forget to notify.